# Не работает ротатион

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 MovementDirection;
    public float Speed;

    private void Start () {
        MovementDirection.Normalize();

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) 
            MovementDirection.y *= -1;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 30);

        transform.Translate(MovementDirection.normalized * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так а где ротатион то? Ты ротатион не делаешь. И, судя по открытой и не закрытой скобке в методе старт, работать здесь не должен не только лишь ротатион.

Comment: if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 30); все работает  кроме  этого

Comment: Это не ротатион. Тебе [сюда](https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html) и [сюда](https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/class-Quaternion.html).

Comment: if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            z += Time.deltaTime * 10;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,z); сделал так но он не при кнопке сработал а сразу встал в то значение которое вводишь в public float

Comment: Скобки открывай после if, ты несколько действий делаешь, а не одно. Тебе [сюда](https://ulearn.me/)